# jquery callback of addClass execute twice

Tags: jquery

I have given an append function on a callback of addClass to an element. But that function executes twice. why?

```js
//append new stage function---------//
var newNode;

function appendNewStage() {
  var parent = $('.ci-journey-interactions-canvas__row');
  var newStage = `<ul class="ci-journey-interactions-canvas__journey-list stage">
    <li>
      <span class="ci-journey-interactions-box__droppable-
element ci-droppable"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>`;

  var position = $(parent).find("ul:last").position();
  var width = $(parent).find("ul:last").outerWidth();
  newNode = $(newStage).appendTo(parent);
  if (remain.length > 0) {
    newNode.html(remain);
  }
  $(newNode).find('li:first-child').addClass('first-child');
  newNode.css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "left": (width + position.left - 89),
    "top": (position.top + 140)
  });
  var dropArea = $(newNode).find('.ci-droppable');
  dropArea.droppable();
  dropArea.droppable({
    accept: ".ci-draggable",
  });
  elementSelect(newNode);
};

//staging  function//
function staged(event) {
  $(".stage:last-child").addClass('staged', function(event) {
    appendNewStage();
  });
  $(".stage").find("li:not('.ui-selected')").remove();
  $(".stage").find("li.blank").remove();
  $(".stage").removeClass("stage");
}
```

I triggering the staged function on a button click event. when I give an alert on staged callback it run two times

Comment: Your logic is flawed as `addClass()` doesn't have a callback. It's not asynchronous.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Some libs, such as [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/), add an animation for `addClass`.

Comment: @TJCrowder You're right. I always forget about jQuery's bastard child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, jQuery's animation callbacks happen **per-element**. So if `$(".stage:last-child")` matches two elements (because there are two `.stage` elements that are the last child in their parent), you'll get two callbacks — one for each element. From the [`animate` documentation](

> **Callback Functions**
>
> If supplied, the `start`, `step`, `progress`, `complete`, `done`, `fail`, and `always` callbacks are called on a *per-element* basis... If multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole. Use the `.promise()` method to obtain a promise to which you can attach callbacks that fire once for an animated set of any size, including zero elements.

So assuming what you're using plays nicely with jQuery's animation internals (the jQuery UI one does):

```
$(".stage:last-child").addClass('staged').promise().then(appendNewStage);
```

Example using jQuery UI's `addClass`:

```js
$(".stage:last-child").addClass("staged", function() {
  console.log("Callback for " + this.id);
})
.promise().then(function() {
  console.log("All done");
});
```

```css
.staged {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="first" class="stage">
    testing 1 2 3
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="second" class="stage">
    testing 9 8 7
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

(I assume you're using [jQuery UI's `addClass` addition](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/) or something else that adds animation to `addClass`. jQuery on its own doesn't animate it, so doesn't have a callback.)

Comment: So, what is the solution for that?

Comment: @sonusasankan: Do you want just one callback when all are done? If so, I've added how you do that above.